# Can't make javascript load .txt file, to load links

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a feature that takes you to a random link, but i got a lot of links at the moment, and was wondering how i could make javascript read a text file that has all the links.

The code that i have right now does not work, i have tried other similar methods but nothing works.

```
<script>
        var sites = [
            function readTextFile("file:///Nicklas Behrend/Desktop/links.txt");
            {
                var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
                rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
                rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
                {
                    if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
                    {
                        if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                        {
                            var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                            alert(allText);
                        }
                    }
                }
                rawFile.send(null);
            }
        ];

        function randomSite() {
            var i = parseInt(Math.random() * sites.length);
            location.href = sites[i];
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: why don't you just make this a json file with links and then with ajax call fetch them

Comment: @VivekN He is doing an AJAX call to fetch them. The difference between a text and JSON file are trivial, code-wise. In this scenario, a text file is probably easier to use.

Comment: @samanime Agreed.My bad, should have made it easier for him.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a syntax error. It should probably be this:

```
var sites = [];
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4) {
      if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
        var allText = rawFile.responseText;
        alert(allText);
        callback(allText);
      }
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}

readTextFile("file:///Nicklas Behrend/Desktop/links.txt", filesText =>{
    sites = filesText.split('\n');
});

function randomSite() {
    var i = parseInt(Math.random() * sites.length);
    location.href = sites[i];
 }
```

You were trying to declare and run the function at the same time, which is all wrong. Also, an `XMLHttpRequest()` is async, so you have to have a callback which will return the text.

Once you have that, you can then split the text into an array of sites (I assumed they were newline-delimited in this case).

Comment: Okay thanks, but now i think that maybe i have located my file in the wrong way or there is something wrong with the link i have in my document, because when i press the button it says ''404 not found''

Comment: @NicklasBehrend I almost guarantee your URL is wrong. The `file://` protocol is based on your file structure. The `/Nicklas Behrend` at the beginning is saying that your folder should be at the root of your file system. That's impossible on Windows (it'd have to start with a drive like `C:/`), and would be really weird on Linux/Mac (it'd have to be at the root). What you can do to get the appropriate URL would be to open the target file in your browser directly, then just copy the URL it gives you.